# How to import LinkIt (custom) fieldtype with Feed Me into Super Table

Tags: import, plugin-feedme, plugin-supertable

I'm trying to import a [LinkIt](https://github.com/fruitstudios/LinkIt) fieldtype into a Super Table with the Feed Me plugin. I've tried several ways but doesn't seem to be working. The part in my json which gets mapped to the Super Table looks like this:

```
"links": [
              {
                "url": "https://imaginehome.canvas.be/en",
                "description": "Imagine Home website"
              }
          ]
```

I've managed to register LinkIt as a Feed Me fieldtype, but no matter what I seem to be returning in the `prepFieldData` function, it will not import it. I have another Super Table field with just some rows with a text input in it and that works just fine.